# Getting the ID of a double clicked item

Tags: c++, qt4, signals

Is it possible to get the name of a double clicked item i.e tables listed in QTableView by their table names?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.
The QTableView emits the `doubleClicked( const QModelIndex &index )` signal and with that you can get the name using the `data( index, role)` method.